# Error in Friedman test

Tags: r, statistics

Good morning,

I wanted to do a Friedman test (from "stats" package) on my data about the leaves of dandelions, but an error is displayed.

My data has the form:

```
> str (mi)

  'data.frame': 4393 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ OS_Gatunek       : Factor w/ 5 levels "Taraxacum ancistrolobum",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PH_CreateDate    : Factor w/ 15 levels "2016-04-06","2016-04-19",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ L_Dl             : num  7.91 8.96 10.18 10.09 9.4 ...
 $ L_SzerMaksOs     : num  1.93 3.98 3.12 4.04 2.75 2.69 3.69 3.23 2.3 2.49 ...
 $ L_DlMax          : num  3.51 4.08 5.58 5.04 3.99 3.6 5.65 4.62 3.33 4.18 ...
 $ KS_DlSk_Sr       : num  1.78 3.28 2.88 4.19 1.88 2.47 3.11 4.04 1.61 2.09 ...
 $ KS_Dl_Sr         : num  1.68 2.83 2.62 3.84 1.68 2.12 2.87 3.8 1.44 1.86 ...
 $ KS_Sz            : num  1.35 3.41 2.38 3.31 1.66 2.35 2.45 2.96 1.57 1.9 ...
 $ KB_DlSkos_Sr     : num  1.07 1.94 1.84 1.69 1.25 1.49 1.96 1.77 1.43 1.55 ...
 $ KB_Dl_Sr         : num  0.62 1.49 1.12 1.34 0.86 0.77 1.22 1.07 0.82 1.05 ...
 $ KB_Szer_Sr       : num  0.85 1.23 1.46 0.94 0.89 1.32 1.53 1.41 1.17 1.14 ...
 $ KB_SzerPierwKlapy: num  1.75 3.99 2.9 4.1 2.34 2.75 3.11 3.39 1.96 2.46 ...
 $ I_Dl_Sr          : num  0.25 0.86 0.48 0.61 0.44 0.41 0.7 0.86 0.14 0.59 ...
 $ I_SzOs           : num  0.37 0.83 0.47 0.87 0.39 0.73 0.53 0.96 0.4 0.33 ...
 $ I_DlSz_Sr        : num  2.3 4.08 3.35 5.23 2.34 3.39 3.22 4.43 1.96 2.55 ...
 $ O_Dl_Sr          : num  0.67 0.75 2.02 0.85 0.74 1.4 1.07 0.26 0.6 0.96 ...
 $ O_SzerOs         : num  1.35 1.59 1.31 0.91 1.08 0.94 1.18 0.84 1.71 0.93 ...
 $ O_SzerOskrz_Sr   : num  0.55 0.65 0.48 0.34 0.39 0.31 0.49 0.29 0.74 0.27 ...
```

The first two columns are indications of my species and dates of measurements, while the others are measurements of various leaf elements (in cm). I will add that the data is mixed up with lines (they are not arranged according to any key).

Typing (as prompted):

```
> friedman.test(mi$L_Dl, groups=mi$OS_Gatunek, blocks=mi$PH_CreateDate)
```

R prints an error message:

```
Error in friedman.test.default(mi$L_Dl, groups = mi$OS_Gatunek, blocks = mi$PH_CreateDate) :
not an unreplicated complete block design
```

I checked, but this is not a problem:
- nor too long string of characters in column 1,
- nor spaces in the same place,
- nor a pause in column 2.

R something compute (but not as I want) if:
 - I transform the tested columns into a matrix (then treats numeric as
   characters),
 - I execute cbind() on the tested columns (then it encodes the species/date names into a numeric form and calculates them as if they were numbers).

I have no other ideas how to solve my problem. I am asking for suggestions.

Regards
Olga Świder

Comment: Are you sure that your data follows an 'unreplicated complete block design', meaning that there is 'exactly one observation in y for each combination of levels of groups and blocks' (as from the function help).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. If I understand you well - for every possible combination of species and date, there should be only one observation. If that's what you mean - it's not (there's a lot more). What should I do then? Extract the average for each combination? Or maybe something else?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. However, what you are looking at is - as far as I understand it - not even a replicated complete block design. Maybe you could look at the `prentice.test` function from the `muStat` package, if this suits your needs and meets your experimental design, but I think it requires a complete design. I am not sure what to do in your case with an replicated uncomplete block design, but I am sure that there is some methods for it as well, but I cannot tell any.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and valuable remarks. I'm definitely looking for something about it. Regards